# Problem installing Oracle 10g Express edition

Tags: installation, uninstall, oracle

I have installed Oracle 10g Express edition in Ubuntu 10.10 and it doesn't show or ask to give my password during installation.

When I click on "start database" it gave the warning "Operation failed, abhi is not a member of 'dba' group." and when clink on "Run SQL command line" it shows `/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/bin/nls_lang.sh: 114: [[: not found`

When I click on "GOTO Database home page", it opens Mozilla's "Ubuntu Google search page".

Can anyone help me get my Oracle to work or tell me how to remove that because it is also not getting removed.
I tried all the commands that are given as suggestions by Ubuntu.

Please help me because I don't want to format my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

For:

```
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/bin/nls_lang.sh: 114: [[: not found
```

The solution is to simply edit it (as root) and remove a pair of square brackets on lines #108 and #110.

Type:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/bin/nls_lang.sh
```

Scroll down until you find this:

```
if [[ -n "$LC_ALL" ]]; then  
  locale=$LC_ALL  
elif [[ -n "$LANG" ]]; then  
  locale=$LANG  
else  
  locale=  
fi
```

Then change it to this (remove a pair of brackets):

```
if [ -n "$LC_ALL" ]; then  
  locale=$LC_ALL  
elif [ -n "$LANG" ]; then  
  locale=$LANG  
else  
  locale=  
fi
```

Then click SAVE. Now try this command again to set your environment variables:

```
/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/bin/oracle_env.sh
```

Nothing appears to happen when you do it but, it auto-sets your variables. DONE!

Enjoy.

Thanks to this blog: http://beardedmagnum.com/2007/09/15/oracle-xe-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

abhi don't worry ... all have solution ... ;)

**Install for 32 bits is easy:**

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://oss.oracle.com/debian unstable main non-free #Oracle XE' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oraclexe.list"

wget http://oss.oracle.com/el4/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle -O- | sudo apt-key add 

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install oracle-xe-universal
```

**for 64 bits:**

```
wget http://oss.oracle.com/debian/dists/unstable/main/binary-i386/libaio_0.3.104-1_i386.deb  http://oss.oracle.com/debian/dists/unstable/non-free/binary-i386/oracle-xe-universal_10.2.0.1-1.1_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture libaio_0.3.104-1_i386.deb oracle-xe-universal_10.2.0.1-1.1_i386.deb 

rm libaio_0.3.104-1_i386.deb oracle-xe-universal_10.2.0.1-1.1_i386.deb
```

**Remove :**

You can use apt-get command to remove / delete Oracle express edition server from the Ubuntu Linux.

Open terminal.

Type the following command to delete it:

> sudo apt-get remove oracle-xe or oracle-xe-universal

**Configure :**

follow this simple an well explain tutorial with screenshot .. it is say how to add your user to dba groups and how to configure oracle to give you a password..

**start in step 1. Configuring Oracle**

[how-to-setup-oracle-10g-xe-in-ubuntu.html](http://lordamit.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-setup-oracle-10g-xe-in-ubuntu.html)

P.D :

About the error ....

you may get an nls_lang error as follows when you try to export the environment variables.

Solution:

ubuntu uses a BASH linux shell. Now open “nls_lang.sh” with a text editor and set the correct shell parameter in the first line of the script.

**see step 5. open nls_lang.sh.**

Answer (score 0):

The nls_lang.sh script has the /bin/sh shebang.

By default Ubuntu links /bin/sh to /bin/dash with can cause somme issues. To fix this link /bin/sh to /bin/bash with is more compatible with /bin/sh:

```
ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh
```